# Get Class of a DIV through VB.net

Tags: vb.net, html

I'm working on a web app that uses javascript to change the classes of 3 div's depending on what buttons the user has pressed.

Is it possible to get the value of the current class of a div?

I tried adding runat="server" to the div tag and then using...

```
thediv.Attributes.CssStyle.Value
```

... to get the value of the class.

But it is returning nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you're trying to do this servers-side?  If all you're doing is changing the classes of divs based on buttons, [jQuery makes this a snap.][1]
  [1]: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a DIV. Use

```
 <asp:Panel ID="TestDiv" runat="server" CssClass="foo"></asp:Panel>
```

and then you can get/set the class with

```
var myClass= TestDiv.CssClass;
```

Or

```
TestDiv.CssClass = "bar";
```

As has been mentioned, using a jquery class selector would accomplish the same thing without the need for postback.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it this way:

```
Dim thediv as HtmlGenericControl = 
    DirectCast(Page.FindControl("divid"), HtmlGenericControl);
thediv.Attributes("class");
```

Comment: Me.divid.Attributes["class"]   (VB)